# Mirroring Uptime Robot Status Page

Tags: iframe, cors

I'm attempting to mirror my Uptime Robot status page (https://stats.uptimerobot.com/DE0RMco2D2) to a server hosted on a custom domain. I'm doing this because I don't want to pay for the Uptime Robot Pro plan, which offers custom domain support. Please note that I've only tested this solution locally.

I have already set up a basic Node.js server using the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const app = new express();
const PORT = 3000;

const fetchWebsite = (url) =\> {
execSync(`curl -o site.html ${url}`, (error, stdout, stderr) =\> {
if (error !== null) {
console.error('Error fetching website:', error);
}
});
};

app.get('/', async (req, res) =\> {
fs.writeFileSync('site.html', '', () =\> console.log('Created site.html'));
fetchWebsite('https://stats.uptimerobot.com/DE0RMco2D2');
fs.createReadStream('site.html').pipe(res);
});

app.listen(PORT, () =\> {
console.log("Listening at port: ", PORT);
});
```

However, when I try to fetch the status page content and serve it, I encounter CORS-related errors.

Is there a way to work around these CORS restrictions to successfully mirror my Uptime Robot status page on my custom domain? I appreciate any guidance.

BTW: no, iframes won't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU0q3.png)